# UITableViewCell Different accessories in one UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm working on writing different accessories for cells in a UITableView.

I need them to be specified as per row basis.

I've written a dataSource NSDictionary that holds the information on the label, imageView and accessory for this purpose.  Label and imageView are pretty straightforward, but I've hit a roadblock of sorts with my accessory.

My idea was to include a block inside my dataSource that returns a UIView. Something like this

```
self.dataSource = @[
    @{
        @"label" : @"This is the Label",
        @"icon" : @"icon_someIconName.png",
        @"accessory" : (UIView*) ^ {
            // code that returns the accessory for this row would go here
            return nil;  // 
        }  
    },
    ... 
];
```

And inside tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...

NSDictionary *cellDataSource = self.dataSource[indexPath.section][@"fields"][indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = cellDataSource[@"label"];
[cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:cellDataSource[@"icon"]]];

// Accessory setup
UIView* (^accessoryBuilderBlock)(void) = cellDataSource[@"accessory"];
if (accessoryBuilderBlock) {
    cell.accessoryView = accessoryBuilderBlock();
}
```

My program crashes at this point.

1. Is there a more efficient way to do this?  I'm fairly new to Objective-C so I don't have a full grasp of best practices.
2. I'm almost positive that the way I'm using the block in my dataSet is not correct, specially because I've read somewhere that under ARC blocks must be copied when inserted inside collections.  Can anyone point me to the correct way (if this is the correct) to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried copying the block? What happens?

Comment: I'm don't know how to do a copy within an Objective-C 2.0 Dictionary literal.  How is it done?

Comment: I added an answer to show how to copy the block.

Answer (score 1):

A problem is surely that you're not copying the block, and if it's a local block, then it will be deallocated out of the current scope. So try to copy it:

```
self.dataSource = @[
    @{
        @"label" : @"This is the Label",
        @"icon" : @"icon_someIconName.png",
        @"accessory" : [(UIView*)^ {
            // code that returns the accessory for this row would go here
            return nil;  // 
        } copy]
    },
    ... 
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using dictionaries, you could create a class to hold your data for your table view's data source. That way, you can use whatever custom logic you like. Like so:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *label;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *icon;

- (UIView *)accessoryView; // Some method to return your accessoryView

@end
```

This would be a much cleaner (and OOP-ey) solution.

Comment: It might be more OOP-ey but it doesn't seem to me cleaner.  the accessoryView method would be huge, having every possible acccessory initialization code in there.

Comment: How may different accessoryViews will there be? If you want to create a bunch of views programatically, the code has to go somewhere. You can also store a block in a property, if that's the kind of approach you want (a quick search here on SO will do the trick).